# CSRF verification failed

Tags: javascript, python, django, xmlhttprequest

I am sending an image file using XMLHttpRequest() in my Django app. This is my script:

```
$('#edit_user_image').change(function(){
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = document.getElementById("edit_user_image");
    /* Create a FormData instance */
    var formData = new FormData();
    /* Add the file */ 
    formData.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value);
    formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);


    client.open("post", "/upload-image/", true);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=frontier");
    client.send(formData);  /* Send to server */ 
  });
```

This is my html input:

```
Upload New Photo
{% csrf_token %}
<input id="edit_user_image" name="image" type="file" />
```

But, when the XMLHttpRequest() is made, it give "CSRF verification failed" error even though I am appending it in the data. Can anyone tell what is wrong in the script.

Comment: Try to set a `X-CSRFToken` header to the value of the CSRF token. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)

Comment: @goliney done, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the changes that I made and now its working fine:

```
$('#edit_user_image').change(function(){
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = document.getElementById("edit_user_image");
    var csrftoken = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
    /* Create a FormData instance */

    var params = file.files[0];


    client.open("post", "/upload-image/", true);
    client.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=frontier");
    client.send(params);  /* Send to server */ 
  });
```